# GVfs Metadata is not supported while Map Reduce Configuration

Tags: system-installation, hadoop

while executing this commond:

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh
```

Getting this error:

```
(gedit:5376): Tepl-WARNING **: 16:32:59.581: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.
```

Comment: Please use `sudo -H gedit`